# Get slow running SOQL information from production

Tags: soql, query, database

Since Salesforce underlying data layer  uses oracle database, can we get information on

1. Slow running SOQL’s in production with times that we can target to improve?
2. Any indexing advice from salesforce support to improve performance of SOQL?

I previously worked on on-premise applications and there we had access to all this information from dBA's. Even in development/review if we miss identifying such queries our DBA's would give us all those information from production and we would find more efficient way to run those queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Query Plan tool to monitor SOQL performance.

For more information, refer [Query Plan Tool (How To & FAQ)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1)

[image: Query plan tool.]

Comment: I know about this but wanted to get this information from production since the data volume for production will be huge in our case and wanted to get some SOQL performance stats to find out slow running queries. I was looking more along event monitoring kind of tool. will explore more on that.

Comment: If you can utilize this tool properly, you can get a good idea about poorly performed queries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Purchase Event Monitoring and you'll get all those metrics.
There's a trailhead module on the product.

Comment: btw, how event monitoring gives the SOQL performance metrices?

Comment: Do you have any documentation about monitoring SOQL performance through event monitoring? I didn't find that out of 45 event types.

Comment: When I worked at Salesforce, we had all the documentation handy, but I don't. I just know that you can see, for example, in a trigger execution, how long a transaction took in the database layer, which is what you're asking.